# Upsert array value in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have a simple scenario where I am trying to update an array value that is part of an object, but the object does not seem to reflect the update.

Code:

```
var request = 
{
  description: 'my-desc',
  details: []
};

request.details['shelf-info'] = 
[
    {
        key: 'ShelfNumber',
        value: '100'
    }
];       

console.log(JSON.stringify(request))
```

With the assignment of `shelf-info`, I would have expected the resulting output to be similar to:

```
Desired Output:

{ "description": "my-desc", "details": { "shelf-info": [ "key": "ShelfNumber", "value": "100" ] } }
```

but the update doesn't seem to have taken effect:

```
Actual Output:

{"description":"my-desc","details":[]}
```

I have found that I can add simple objects (strings) to an array using `append`, but `shelf-info` may or may not already be in the `request.details` section by the time this code gets executed...how would I handle both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a plain object (`{}`) for `details`, not an array (`[]`).

When arrays are serialized to JSON, the JSON output only includes values that are stored in whole-number indices. Arrays may validly have other properties whose key names are not non-negative integers (such as the string `shelf-info`) but those properties are not included the JSON serialization of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an array as if it's an object, which it technically is, but that won't add anything to the array, and it won't convert the array to a regular object with key/value pairs.

Easy fix:

```
var request = {
  description: 'my-desc',
  details: { }
};
```

Also since it's 2020 you should be using `let` instead of `var` in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below. Detail property should be an object.

```
var request = 
{
  description: 'my-desc',
  details: {}
};

request.details['shelf-info'] = 
[
    {
        key: 'ShelfNumber',
        value: '100'
    }
];       

console.log(JSON.stringify(request))
```